# Start() function doesn't work properly after Application.LoadLevel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my start function works fine when i start a scene but after reloading it or going to another level it has some problems.
When my player dies i hide some canvas elements and show "restart" and "mainMenu" buttons. but when i reload the game reset/mainMenu buttons are still shown and other elements that i had hidden when player died are still hidden ?!

```
    void Start () {

    Debug.Log("LOL");
    mainMenu.SetActive(false);
    reset.SetActive(false);
}

void Update()
{
    bool r = true;
    if(Player.Life <= 0 && r == true)
    {
        reset.SetActive(true);
        mainMenu.SetActive(true);
        panel.SetActive(false);

        r = false;
    }
}
```

UPDATE :
Suddenly my problem has solved?!!
i just closed and opened my project again and it works correctly ?!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the log? Does the object with this script exist in the new level?

Comment: yes it exists. and i getting this message :  cleaning up leaked objects in scene since no game object, component or manager is referencing them. mesh has been leaked to times.

Comment: You have monobehaviours taking up memory in yoru game with nothing referencing them. I would either look into object pooling or inspect the ways in which you are handling destroying objects. If you do not destroy objects which you do not need anymore this will happen